# Update model attributes in a new controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes, simple-form-for

I have two models implemented User and Order with their own Controllers being used by AdminController.
Now I need to edit/update this model from Client with a ClientController.

I've created the following so far:

```
class Client::BaseController < ApplicationController
end

class Client::OrdersController < Client::BaseController
end

class ClientArea::UsersController < ClientArea::BaseController
end
```

I tried to add a new action to UserController in order to get the attributes of the User model and then change its password:

```
def update_password
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
end
```

and added the following to my view/client/user/update_password

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :email, :label => 'Your email please' %>
   <%= f.input :crypted_password, :hint => 'No special characters.' %>#   <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean %>
   <%= f.button :submit %>
 <% end %>
```

I know this is not the write code to update some attribute, but just with this code I'm already getting this error:

*undefined method `individual_path' for #<#:0x007ffef8d06930>*

I believe this error comes from the ClientController not-knowing the Model User, but I'm not sure, and I have no idea of how I could do this.